# What additional things should I do to understand language of science

Tags: soft-question, education, mathematics

I am about to complete my High school. Typically, I study text books of science but it takes a lot of time to understand the concept resulting less time to do questions and due to which I get low marks(not having English as my native language is also a factor). How should I start, please guide me from basic to advance level.

- How could I study science, effectively, without wasting any time.

Comment: Just carry on studying at school. If it's a good school they will help you learn the main contours of science and where you might want to specialise; science is a huge subject these days and it's best to pace yourself rather than be impatient for short-cuts.

Comment: Thankyou Mozibur, I also realised that I am being impatient.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd add that it's quite common for child prodigies to burn out just because they don't pace themselves; the administration of science is there to help guide people in their career - not to stalk them. As you progress in your career you should find this out.

Comment: Plus you're young. Living is also about making a life and this is something else that needs to be discovered: there's an old English proverb that goes: All work and no play makes Jack a very dull boy! There's a lot of truth in this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the best ways is to enroll in a full time University course but of course that is a lot of commitment. If you don't want to do that then I would suggest looking for University lectures on YouTube. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUl4u3cNGP61-9PEhRognw5vryrSEVLPr) is a full quantum mechanics module by MIT, it doesn't get much better than that! Don't start with that module though. Universities' websites will have a list of the modules that they teach and use that as a guide for what you should learn first. Try to find problem sheets online as well so that you're constantly practicing the skills you learn.